# jQuery animate() only working on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm creating a menu that appears after a click on a link, and I'm trying to use the jQuery animate(); function to slide it in rather than just having it appear.

The issue I'm having is that it only seems to activate the sliding bit on the second attempt, although it does seem to do the 500ms pause as though it were.

I've seen a bunch of other questions about this but the answers are either "you've got a specific error in your code" or "you have to toggle or otherwise fake the animation on page load". I'm hoping my code is error-free and I'm not really keen to use a toggle hack just to bypass the first animation no-show.

Presumably this is supposed to work first time & every subsequent time so my question is: How do I get the animation to work first time without an onload fix/hack?

**HTML**

```
<section id="mover">
  <div class="menu_Content">
    <div class="menu_close"> 
        <a href="#" id="closeMenu">close menu</a>
    </div>
     <h5><a href="/">[menu link]</a></h5>
     <h5><a href="/">[menu link]</a></h5>
     <h5><a href="/">[menu link]</a></h5>
     <h5><a href="/">[menu link]</a></h5>
     <h5><a href="/">[menu link]</a></h5>
     <h5><a href="/">[menu link]</a></h5>
     <h5><a href="/">[menu link]</a></h5>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="core home">
  <header>
    <div class="menu_link"> <a href="#" id="openMenu">[menu]</a></div>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
     <h1 class="big-head">[headline one]</h1>
     <p>[some content]</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mover {
    background:rgba(47, 47, 47, 1);
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0%;
}
#mover a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#mover .menu_close {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #FF7466;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
//menu open
jQuery('#openMenu').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#mover')
        .animate({
        right: '0%'
    }, 500, function () {
        jQuery('#mover').show();
    });
});
//menu close
jQuery('#closeMenu').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#mover').animate({
        right: '100%'
    }, 500);
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/05gu7bpr/4/

Thanks!

Comment: +1. All SO questions should be formed like this. As an aside, have you considered using CSS transitions instead? This doesn't answer your question, but is often my preferred approach to browser-based animation now.

Comment: I want it to work on click only so JS seemed the way to go, I'm open to any solution though and generally prefer a CSS option. What's a SO question?

Comment: StackOverflow question. I'll write the CSS alternative for you in the morning. But basically, you toggle a class with your jQuery. One class will have `right: 0%;` and the other will have `right: 100%`. This will snap on click now (obviously), but then you define the transition like so: `transition: all 3s ease;`. The `all` means any difference in CSS properties will be animated where possible, you could've just had `right` but I assume you might want to play around with it so left `all` in. NOTE: Check for `-webkit` equivalents of transition attributes etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `#mover` CSS to this:

```
#mover {
    background:rgba(47, 47, 47, 1);
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/hmwuu5zv/)

Comment: Darn it. So it was an error, more practice in checking required... fancy putting right in twice *groan*.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/desmo/05gu7bpr/5/

The show happen after the animation on the first click

I corrected the css and the js

css:

```
#mover {
    background:rgba(47, 47, 47, 1);
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
#mover a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#mover .menu_close {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #FF7466;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
    //menu open
jQuery('#openMenu').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#mover')
        .animate({
        right: '0%'
    }, 500);
});
//menu close
jQuery('#closeMenu').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#mover').animate({
        right: '100%'
    }, 500);
});
```